# What fonts does iPad have? Or Omnigraffle on iPad?

Tags: fonts, ipad

I'm interested in getting an iPad to use Omnigraffle.  I'm a 5-year+ Omnigraffle fan on Mac, and so far it looks like reviews say that Omnigraffle on iPad has all the same features, except for Applescript.

But what about fonts?

Can iPad, or the Omnigraffle app specifically, support using any font file that I can get ahold of, like the Mac?

Answer (score 2):

Here is [a list of all the fonts that come with iOS](http://iosfonts.com/), categorised by the operating system version and the type of device.

Answer (score 1):

As of version 1.8.1 - November 2, 2012 Omnigraffle for iPad has the following fonts available:

- Didot
- Futura
- Georgia
- Gill Sans
- Helvetica Neue
- Hoefler Text
- Optima
- Palatino

From the Omnigraffle web site:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Omnigraffle for the iPad comes with a selection of fonts to choose from, but you can not add any of your own fonts to the iPad version.

Comment: The great sad truth of iOS's lock down on the system: You can't add stuff to make it better.